# Terminal de NodeJS ejecuta .load de manera infinita

Tags: javascript, nodejs, backend, terminal

Estoy empezando con NodeJS y estoy viendo los comandos basicos del REPL, el interprete integrado de Node, todo esto en la terminal de VSCode. El problema es cuando intento cargar un archivo con .load, lo que tenia entendido es que si cargo un script con load tengo disponibles en la terminal todo el codigo de ese script para usarlo o modificar las variables que tiene dentro por ejemplo. El tema es que se carga solo la primera linea del script y lo hace infinitamente, solo me carga esa linea y no el resto del script. Ni siquiera con CTRL C puedo detener el programa. Les paso el codigo del script y las fotos del directorio raiz y como me muestra el error la terminal:

1_dentro del directorio raiz y en la terminal escribo `node`. Se abre el interprete

2_para cargar el script escribo `.load 1_Install_Basics/myscripts.js`

3_se produce el error, carga la primera linea infinitamente

[image: Directorio Raiz]

[image: Error]

El script es sencillo:

```
let names = ['juan','maria','ricardo','lucia'];

names = names.map((elem, index) => {
  return `Hola ${elem}!! tu indice en el array es ${index}`
});

console.log(names);
```

También me sucede lo mismo si en vez de la terminal en VSCode uso el símbolo del sistema de Windows, sigue teniendo el mismo comportamiento. No sé bien que está pasando estoy empezando con Node.

Comment: Si haces node load 1_Install_Basics/myscripts.js pasa lo mismo? yo lo probe y no hay errores.

Comment: @SantiagoMartinez si pongo ese comando con el REPL cerrado me tira error, y con el REPL abierto tambien... sera algo de la instalacion de node o del equipo? :( que raro que te funcione, debe ser de aca de mi computadora.

Comment: el comando .save me anda perfectamente, tengo la version v19.3.0